# jQuery selector only selecting the last checkbox column but should select all checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm trying to highlight the entire row when a user checks any checkboxes inside the `<table>`.  I'm using the "dataTable" plugin for jquery.

I'm able to get part of this working the way I want it.  Currently the far right, or last column that have "checkboxes" get the selector applied to it.  So, when I check a box (either the check_all box in the "th" or a checkbox in the "td" it highlights the row properly.  But if I check any checkbox in the 2nd to last column nothing happens.  It's acting like the selector didn't get applied here.

I don't understand what's wrong with my jQuery.

Here's my jquery:

```
//SELECTED ROW HIGHLIGHT
$("table.datatable_ss").delegate("input:checkbox", "click", function( e ) {
    //Search the body for any checked input boxes and highlight the row
    $("table.datatable_ss tbody [type=checkbox]").each(function(){
            if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
                $(this).closest("tr").addClass("row_selected");
            }
            else {
                $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("row_selected");
            }
    });
});
```

Heres the html:

```
<table class="datatable_ss">
    <thead>
         <tr>
        <th>Suite</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="_arch_chbx_checkall"></th>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="_del_chbx_checkall" ></th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class=" sorting_1">Suite 301</td>
            <td>Mainstreet Plaza</td>
            <td>Active</td>
            <td>06/01/2012</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="input_editible" name="_arch_chbx" id="9_L_arch_chbx">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="input_editible" name="_delete_chbx" id="9_L_del_chbx">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your HTML seems to be wrong in several places. `<thead>` should have table rows, `<tr>` , underneath which should in turn have headers, `<th>`, underneath. Further you didnt close `<thead>`. The `<th>` tag is analogous to the `<td>` tag, FYI.

Comment: sorry, i just typed that in wrong...the actual code has it right. i fixed in now.

Comment: as you use tbody in the selector.. the <thead> checkboxes are ignored! at line 6 of js code

Answer (score 0):

I got the highlight to work by removing the loop through of the checkboxes. I think it is better to separate out the select-all checkbox event wire-up and the row-checkbox event wire up.

```
// this will wire up the click for each individual row
$("table.datatable_ss tbody").delegate("input:checkbox", "click", function( e ) {

    //Search the body for any checked input boxes and highlight the row
    //$("table.datatable_ss tbody [type=checkbox]").each(function(){
            if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) 
            {
                $(this).closest("tr").addClass("row_selected");                 
            }
            else 
            {
                $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("row_selected");
            }
    //});
});
```

Comment: great..thanks I changed the code.  Now the only thing I need is for the rows to be highlighted if they check the "check_all" checkboxes that are located in the <thead>...I guess thats why I used the .each(), but the .each() was causing my original problem...any ideas?  Thanks for the reply

Comment: This code wont work when you have multiple checked items & if you uncheck one it will remove "row_selected" class. i.e you still have checked items inside your row

Comment: Yes, the "each()" would run through all the checkboxes. If you want to highlight a row if either one of the checkbox is checked, you can "return false" from the "if" condition to break out of the each() loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use foreach thats what causing problem.

Try this.

```
 $("table.datatable_ss").delegate("input:checkbox", "click", function (e) {
          if ($(this).closest("tr").find("input:checkbox:checked").length > 0) {
               $(this).closest("tr").addClass("row_selected");
          }
          else {
               $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("row_selected");
          }
 });
```

Comment: this works, but not for multiple checkboxes...ie see ulhas Tuscano's comments above.  it also does not "check all" and highlight the rows...but it did help me think differently to come up with a solution.  see my reply below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies.  It helped me figure out a solution that worked for allscenarios:

I ended up having a separate selector for just the "thead" input boxes that would highlight all the rows if a checkbox in that row happened to be checked.

The other selector is for the "tbody" checkboxes, and traversing up to the "tr" then using .find() allowed me to check to see if there was a checkbox checked, if so, the row stayed highlighted.

Thanks for all those that helped me trigger a new way of thinking about this.

Heres the updated jquery:

```
//SELECTED ROW HIGHLIGHT for the THEAD "select all" checkboxes
                        $("'.$selector.' thead input:checkbox").click( function( e ) {

                            var xRow = $("'.$selector.' tbody tr");

                            //Search the body for any checked input boxes and highlight the row
                            if ( xRow.find("input").is(":checked") ) //find all checkboxes
                            {
                                xRow.addClass("row_selected");
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                xRow.removeClass("row_selected");
                            }

                        });

                        //SELECTED ROW HIGHLIGHT
                        $("'.$selector.'").delegate("input:checkbox", "click", function( e ) {

                            //Search the body for any checked input boxes and highlight the row
                            if ( $(this).closest("tr").find("input").is(":checked") ) //find all checkboxes
                            {
                                $(this).closest("tr").addClass("row_selected");
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("row_selected");
                            }

                        });
```